# Как реализовать генерацию документации по нужному проекту?

Tags: c#

Я написал генерацию документации по определенному апи.
Расписывать логику не имеет смысла, но на выходе мы получаем json документ с документацией.

Теперь задача следующая: запускать генерацию вместе с билдом проекта/ов

*Запустил проект с апи -> запустилась генерация -> создалась папка с документом в проекте*

*Запустил 10 проектов -> запустилась генерация для каждого проекта -> создалась папка для каждого проекта со своей документацией*

Вопрос: как адекватно это сделать? Мб msbuild tasks как-то использовать в данном случае?
input для таски будет какой-то проект, а output - папка в этом проекте, но я совсем не уверен. Подскажите, как правильно все это сделать?

Comment: Да, можно использовать MS Build. Можно использовать любой скриптовый язык (powershell, bash), смотря где и как собираете. А ещё можете посмотреть на Cake и Nuke - системы сборки на C#.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Получается, создаю ms build task, где input параметр - это проект, который запускается, а output - это папка в этом проекте, так?